# Creation of many identical objects C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create an object in the flowLayoutPanel on the click of a button, identical to those that are already there. So that the same properties remain, but the name of the object changes (For example, block1 was copied and the new object was called block2). How can this be done in C# Windows Form?

Comment: by object you mean a `Control` such as a textbox, or button etc?

Comment: What about serialization or reflection? Also do you want to be able to add arbitrary controls and copy all properties or you know the control and properties you want to copy?

Comment: what type of control is it? Or do you actually want to dynamically create a new instance of any type of control?

Comment: "those that are already there" were created by code.  Just run that code again.

Comment: Build a mini-Factory that always generates Controls with the same properties and only use this Factory to create new Controls. -- The name assigned to a Control is not important, its Reference counts more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to implement `IClonable` in your control. Then, you can implement the `Clone` method, which will give you control over which properties you'd like to clone.

```cs
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, ICloneable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lblName.Text = this.Name;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        MyUserControl? result = Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType()) as MyUserControl;

        if (result != null)
        {
            foreach (var control in this.Controls)
            {
                // Clone child controls or properties as needed
            }
        }

        return result ?? this;
    }
}
```

Then, in your button click event, you can do:

```cs
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the "master" control to clone from
    var userControl = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[0] as MyUserControl;

    if (userControl != null)
    {
        for (int x = 2; x < 10; x++)
        {
            MyUserControl? clone = userControl.Clone() as MyUserControl;

            if (clone != null)
            {
                clone.Name = $"Block {x}";
                        
                this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(clone);
            }
        }
    }
}
```